# Finite parameter integral implies finite norm

Tags: integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Need a bit of help with a parameter integral problem.

We have, $X$ is a finite measure space with measure $\mu$ and $f:X\rightarrow [0 , \infty)$  is a measurable function.

The parameter integral is defined as

$$\psi (t) := \int_{X} \exp(-tf(x)).$$

I have already shown that this is a continuous function of $t  \in[0 , \infty)$.

I have also shown that if  $ f\in L^{m}(x) $  for some $m\ \epsilon \ \mathbb{N}$ then the $k$-th derivative is
$(-1)^{k}\left \| f \right \|_{k}^{k}$    where $k = 1 , 2 ,\dots , m$.

My question is, assuming there exists $\varepsilon > 0  $ such that  $\psi(t) < \infty$  for all
$t \in(-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon )$.
How do I show $\left \| f \right \|_{p}< \infty $   for all $1 < p < \infty$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With $t:=-\varepsilon/2$, we get $$\int_X\exp\left(\frac\varepsilon 2f(x)\right)\mathrm d\mu(x)<\infty.$$
Since $s^k/k!\leqslant \sum_{j=0}^\infty s^j/j!=e^s$ for each positive $s$, this implies that $f$ belongs to $\mathbb L^k$ for each positive integer $k$. Indeed, 
$$\left(\frac{\varepsilon}2\right)^k\frac 1{k!}\int_Xf(x)^k\mathrm d\mu(x)<\infty.$$
If $K\int |g(x)|\mathrm d\mu(x)$ is finite for some positive constant $K$, then $\int |g(x)|\mathrm d\mu(x)$ is finite.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure that I follow you at all sorry. So you are saying that for $t\ \epsilon\ (-\varepsilon /2, \varepsilon /2)
$  then the integral  
$\int _{X} exp(-tf(x))\ d\mu (x)$  
will always be less than infinity??  
If so then where is the following argument coming from. Thanks for your help

Comment: It is true for $|t|\lt\varepsilon$ (by the assumption), hence it is in particular true for $t:=-\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: ahhh, that was silly. So from this is your arguement then:  
Let $s:=\frac{\epsilon }{2}f(x)$  
We now know from our integral that the integral of the exponential of this over X is finite.  
We have the convenient result that $s^k/k!\leqslant e^s$ for each positive $s$. (where does this result come from btw?)  
So   $\int _{X}s^k/k!\leqslant \int _{X}e^s \leqslant \infty$  
How does this relate back to a finite norm, how does the $k!$ change things?

Comment: @Cameron See edit.

Comment: Understanding it now. Thanks for all your help